# flask socketio background thread restart or stop while it's sleeping

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I've implement a webpage, the user can change settings for how often the background task repeats.
The thread always have to wait for the sleep ends, what I want is I can interrupt the sleep, and restart the background task immediately so I can sleep with the newest time from the database, how can I achieve this?

```
def on_connect():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        app = current_app._get_current_object()
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread, app=app)
def background_thread:
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            time = Time.query.first().interval
            socketio.sleep(time)
```

Comment: You can use an event object instead of sleep. This article can help: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-make-python-wait.

Comment: @Miguel, changing socketio.sleep to an event object blocks all the operations in my web, how can I make it work in socketio thread asynchronously? I've searched through asyncio event, but I got confused, I don't think adding async to my socketio thread is the way. much thanks for your reply.

Comment: I did not mean you should use asyncio, that actually does not work with Flask or with Flask-SocketIO. There is an Event object in the threading module (if you use the "threading" async_mode of Flask-SocketIO) or in event and gevent (if you use any of these as async_mode). You have to use the Event object that is compatible with your async_mode for things to work.